# Why is this console log affected by a subsequent if statement?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
var a = 'a';

function b() {
    console.log(a);

    if (!a) {
        var a = 'b';
    }
}

b();
```

Running `b()` prints `undefined` to the console. However, if you remove the `if` statement, or even simply remove the `var` keyword from the expression within the `if` statement so that you're redefining the outer `a` variable, the string `a` will be printed to the console as expected.

Can anyone explain this? The only cause I can think of is that this is a race condition, and the `if` statement is running just a tad faster than the `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a race condition - it's a language feature and is working as the designers of the Javascript language intended.

Because of hoisted variable definitions (where all variable definitions within a function scope are hoisted to the top of the function), your code is equivalent to this:

```
var a = 'a';

function b() {
  var a;
  console.log(a);

  if (!a) {
    a = 'b';
  }
}

b();
```

So, the locally declared `a` hides the globally declared `a` and initially has a value of `undefined` until your `if` statement gives it a value.

You can find lots of discussion about this characteristic of the Javascript language by searching for `"Javascript hoisting"`.

Comment: Ah, did not understand that hoisting would affect variables within a conditional, but since blocks don't matter in ES5 I guess that makes sense. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you use `var` statement in a function, it will be creating a new variable which is local to that function.
2. All the variables declared in the function, will be moved to the top of the function, irrespective of the place where they are actually declared. This is called *Hoisting*.
3. The hoisted variables will have the value `undefined`, by default, till they are explicitly assigned a value.

It prints `undefined` as it is, because of the 3rd point.

In your case, you declared a variable `a` within the `if` block. Since the variables are hoisted, the declaration is moved to the top of the function. It has the same name as the outer variable. When you access `a` in the function, it first looks in the current scope if there is a variable by that name exists. It checks other scopes only if it is not found in local scope. So, the local `a` shadows the outer `a`. When you remove the var statement, there is no `a` in local scope, so the outer `a` is used. That is why it prints `a`.